# why i can't extends AppCompatActivity in my activity class?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When i extends my activity class by **AppCompatActivity** it gave me **Cannot resolve symbole AppCompatActivity**.
I used the imports in my gradle but it does not works...

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

## Activity class

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;//Cannot resolve symbole AppCompatActivity
public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity{//Cannot resolve symbole AppCompatActivity
.
.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mymain);
    intilaizs();
    action();
}
.
.
```

## My Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.me.menu_2"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile project(':MenuLibrary')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar')
}
```

Comment: call only `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"` then clean-rebuild-gradle

Comment: @intelli-amiya  i do it but...

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 23`

Comment: i do not want the sdk version

Comment: @intelli-amiya can i change it to sdk 17 or 19 ?

Comment: Add design support in gradle file. i.e.,    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'

Comment: @saritha-g its work. but how i can change it to sdk 17 ?

Comment: y do you want to change..? that will support for API level 7 or higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following line in gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have not the 23.3.0 repository. I change it to 23.0.0 worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'`